# Javascript/jQuery - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have tried looking on stackoverflow for answers to this problem and tried the solutions before but none of them seemed to work.

I have a textbox inside of a gridview that I want to use the jQuery autocomplete feature for. However, when I run my code, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

These are my files and javascript/jquery function:

```js
var data = [
"test1",
"test2",
"test3",
"test4",
"test5"];
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#MainContent_Gridview1_txtAddMemberName_0").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            autoFocus: true,
        });
    }
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="MainContent_Gridview1_txtAddMemberName_0" />
```

Comment: @JulienD no it's not.

Comment: @maxblade I change your code to snippet, everything works there... you sure this is the exact code you have?

Comment: @OP double-check the `id` of the element, particularly the spelling. And make sure you didn't accidentally use `id="#..."`

Comment: Even if there was a problem with the `id` - when you use `jquery` the selector returns a jquery object that will have the `autocomplete` function in case jquery-ui was loaded correctly. It will do nothing, but you will not get an error for that...

Comment: this is the exact error that I get: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (createNew:149)
    at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1148)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.9.1.js:433)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.9.1.js:103)

Comment: also I am not sure about the id of the textbox - i followed some other post's advice and got the id from the textbox by viewing the page source while the page was running (is this a correct way of doing it?). Again, the textbox is inside of a gridview.